# updating measure calculation to apply OR logic in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to have my dimensions filter a calculation using the OR logic.  I have 3 tables: 1 Fact and 2 Dimensions.

```
 SalesFact: SalesID, ProductID, StoreID
 ProductDim: ProductID, ProductName
 StoreDim: StoreID, StoreName
```

This is the measure:

```
       Total SalesId =    
             CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(SalesFact[SalesID])          
       )
```

This works good, but I want it to filter on *either* dimension selected, something like this:

```
EVALUATE
    SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
    FILTER(
            SalesFact,
            SalesFact[ProductId]=15257 
            || SalesFacts[StoreId]=19732
            || SalesFacts[StoreId]=19738
            ),      
    "Total Sale IDs", [Total SalesId]
```

)

How can I put this directly into the measure definition so when ProductA is selected and StoreB, I get the total count of SaleIds with either ProductA or StoreB?

Thank you!

Comment: Is SalesID a primary key in the fact table?

Comment: Yes, SalesID is PK of SalesFact table.

Comment: I assume your model is correct  and you have made the connections. Based on this, Why do you use a measure and not simply the card visualization?

Comment: I step out, you do not need my help.